# Trigger for take daily backup of sql server database

Tags: sql-server

I work on database task. I have to take database backup at all day at 12:00 AM.

I can't find trigger for it but i find one job for it on this.

[Job for backup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlagent/archive/2010/10/12/create-a-database-backup-job-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx) for backup database and also it work good but I want trigger if it is possible.

Please any help.

Comment: Use a **SQL Server Agent Job** for this - not a trigger. An agent job can be scheduled for a particular time, e.g. 12AM - a trigger cannot. A trigger happens when some action (`INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE`) in a database table happens - that's **not** the ideal place to start a lengthy operation like a backup

Comment: @Devart why bad idea i can't get ? any other way then which i used. ?

Comment: I'm sorry - I really **don't understand** what it is you're asking for..... use a job for this, when you create a job, you can define when and how often it runs - what more do you need? What are you trying to do that you cannot do right now??

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use triggers to initiate a database backup.

The correct approach for this is to put the SQL you have to take the database backup into a SQL Server Agent job and to schedule that job at whatever time you want it to "trigger" off. I recommend you pick the schedule time when you know there is minimal to no activity on your SQL Server so the database backup does not impact the SQL Server performance.